# How to keep proportions between elements in layout (independent to screen size)?

Tags: android, android-layout

I made chat activity. But I have a problem with it. On the bottom of the [layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xgEee.png) there is some empty space and I don't know why and how, because on the preview (the same screen as my phone) empty space is ideally used. When I play this activity on my phone, empty space "magically" show up. I think it's because size of the elements is hardcoded into xml and it's not flexible to screen change. I want to keep proportions between elements using weights. I want to set **android:weightSum** to screen height in **dp** (because I have coded elements size in dp) and change **android:weight** of each element to their actual height. But I don't know how to obtain screen height in dp (I have [information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UPk13.png) about my screen in pixels) Is this approach solve the problem of empty space and achieve screen flexibility?

There is activity layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_welcome"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="xxx.xx.xxxxxxx.WelcomeActivity">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="58dp"
        android:background="#545454">

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageButton
            android:layout_width="55dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/icarrowbackblack24dp"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:id="@+id/imageButton"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:background="@drawable/image_button"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />

        <TextView
            android:text="xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx"
            android:layout_width="140dp"
            android:layout_height="23dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="18dp"
            android:id="@+id/textView19"
            android:textSize="17dp"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="9dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageButton" />

        <TextView
            android:text="xxxxxxx(x) xxxxx"
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:id="@+id/textView21"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView19"
            android:textSize="12dp"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView19"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="459dp">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/relative_layout"
        android:layout_height="459dp"
        android:background="#d3d3d3">

        <ListView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="459dp"
            android:id="@+id/messegesListView"
            android:divider="@null"
            android:dividerHeight="3dp"
            android:paddingBottom="6dp"
            android:listSelector="@drawable/listview_background"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true">
        </ListView>
    </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="43dp"
        android:background="#ffffff">
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="43dp"
        android:background="#ffffff">
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="325dp"
            android:layout_height="43dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:hint="xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx..."
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:id="@+id/editText" />

        <Button
            android:text=">"
            android:layout_width="43dp"
            android:layout_height="43dp"
            android:id="@+id/button10"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:background="@drawable/button"
            android:textColor="@color/button_text_color"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

        <Button
            android:text=""
            android:layout_width="43dp"
            android:layout_height="43dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:id="@+id/button11"
            android:background="@drawable/button"
            android:textColor="@color/button_text_color"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/button10" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things that I feel are important for you to understand:

- Do not add the `ListView` within a `ScrollView`. The `ListView` can handle it's own scroll events.
- Setting height of a view to hard-coded values (like `459dp` in this case) might give poor appearance on some devices. This is where the concept of `layout_weights` come in handy.

This is how I have implemented your layout.

- I have removed the `ScrollView`
- I have set the `layout_weight` of `ListView` to 1 and changed it's `layout_height` to `0dp`. This ensures that the list view takes up any unoccupied space in the layout.

  ```
  <RelativeLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="58dp"
      android:background="#545454">

      <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageButton
          android:layout_width="55dp"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
          android:id="@+id/imageButton"
          android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
          android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />

      <TextView
          android:text="xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx"
          android:layout_width="140dp"
          android:layout_height="23dp"
          android:layout_marginStart="18dp"
          android:id="@+id/textView19"
          android:textSize="17dp"
          android:textColor="#ffffff"
          android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
          android:layout_marginTop="9dp"
          android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageButton" />

      <TextView
          android:text="xxxxxxx(x) xxxxx"
          android:layout_width="120dp"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:textColor="#ffffff"
          android:id="@+id/textView21"
          android:layout_below="@+id/textView19"
          android:textSize="12dp"
          android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView19"
          android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
  </RelativeLayout>

  <ListView
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="0dp"
      android:layout_weight="1"
      android:id="@+id/messegesListView"
      android:divider="@null"
      android:dividerHeight="3dp"
      android:paddingBottom="6dp">
  </ListView>


  <RelativeLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="43dp"
      android:background="#ffffff">
  </RelativeLayout>

  <RelativeLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="43dp"
      android:background="#ffffff">

      <EditText
          android:layout_width="325dp"
          android:layout_height="43dp"
          android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
          android:hint="xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx..."
          android:background="@android:color/transparent"
          android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
          android:id="@+id/editText" />

      <Button
          android:text=">"
          android:layout_width="43dp"
          android:layout_height="43dp"
          android:id="@+id/button10"
          android:scaleType="fitCenter"
          android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
          android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

      <Button
          android:text=""
          android:layout_width="43dp"
          android:layout_height="43dp"
          android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
          android:id="@+id/button11"
          android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/button10" />
  </RelativeLayout>
  ```